# How to install NASM in windows 10?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to learn assembly and want to download NASM
I use Windows 10,is it possible to install NASM without using DosBox or VM ?? because I saw someone using CodeBlocks with NASM to code in assembly..

Comment: Yes. Look [here](https://www.nasm.us/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

NASM has installers for Windows available from its website under the "Downloads" tab

The latest stable Win64 build (as of 4/4/2024) is available here: https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.16.02/win64/

Comment: Note :- To add nasm in command prompt just add path of nasm folder in which nasm.exe is located to environment variable PATH  and save it then you will be able to access nasm from anywhere in cmd

Comment: @VikasKandari, can you please help me what EXACTLY the command or path to be added to the environment? I ran my NASM in the path/folder where it is installed, it doesn't works. I downloaded the exe file from the link given above.

Comment: its been a while since i used the nasm , but i am pretty sure there be a bin folder on which you will either find .exe files or binary file without extention , so to run the .exe file just do /nasm-installation-folder/bin/nasm.exe -param1 -param2 etc , or simple add the bin directory to environment variable path

Answer (score 9):

An easy alternative for Windows 10 would be installing NASM with the [winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) Package Manager.

Run the Command Prompt as an Administrator and then:

**Install NASM**

```
winget install nasm -i
```

**Add it to the Environment Variables**

```
C:\Program Files\NASM
```

Or alternatively with [setx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx):

*Be cautious as it may overwrite your current variables* (It didn't for me)

```
setx Path "%Path%;C:\Program Files\NASM\"
```

**Restart the Command Prompt and verify**

```
nasm --version
```

> NASM version 2.15.05 compiled on Aug 28 2020

Comment: Warning that the "setx Path" is bad, you will trash your path variable if it's > 1024 characters as it will truncate it.

Comment: Dude put a warning before `setx Path "%Path%;C:\Program Files\NASM\"`. It will remove all other env variables

Comment: is this install location particular to winget? Because I just installed NASM with installer and it's not where you say it is.